# Modeling Gaussian Beam Focusing

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, laser

I am trying to model beam focusing using machine learning algorithms in Python with the goal of building a model that learns to focus the beam to the smallest point possible. However, I am lost as to how to represent the physics behind beam focusing.

Looking online, I am thinking that the changing the beam focus (aka beam waist) would be the input and the beam radius + intensity would be the output, but I still fail to understand the connection between how changing the focus affects the output variables, so I am unable to piece together the model. Could somebody shed some light on the physical connection?

Comment: Gaussian optics?

Comment: yes, gaussian optics

Comment: I know that your optics skills are not the best, but I think you need to be more specific.  It's not clear what you are trying to do, what your inputs will be, what your outputs will be, what approximations you are willing to make. What is your model allowed to vary? etc

Comment: my model is trying to simulate the act of changing the focus of an electron microscope (input) and its effect on the radius and intensity of the resulting beam (output) to have the model gradually learn to focus to the smallest point possible. it seems from my reading that this is an optimization problem. is that correct? also, not exactly sure on what approximations can be made, but starting with a basic model of the beam propagation should be fine

Comment: I'm no expert on electron optics, but I don't think you want the optics of a Gaussian beam.  You need to account for the mutual repulsion of the electrons, the energy of the electrons, the  effect of the induced magnetic field ...  Can you tell us the context of the exercise?  Why are you doing it?  That will help us get you started.

Comment: I am not focusing on the additional factors just yet (starting with a basic model), so a gaussian model should work as a basic framework to start for the moment. I am doing this as part of my university undergrad research (my bio is a bit outdated) trying to simulate a few EM tasks like beam centering and focusing

Comment: Just a quick question. Why does it need to be machine learning for something predictable? Both the laser beam and the electron focus seem something a physical model could achieve with a few inputs. Yes, it can also be an optimization problem that could also be solved either with a heuristic algorithm or a gradient descent kind when doing things blindly (without assumptions of the problem at hand), but I would only consider machine learning when having to apply such a program to random parts/system.

Comment: Although I want to understand what you mean by the input focus and output radius and intensity, do you mean, in the same physical location? Or the input focus is in one location and the output focus is in another? Because if its the same location, focus, radius and intensity are all kind of the same type of information.

Comment: I am also trying to understand the problem to see if it is solvable/should be solved using machine learning. Yes, the input focus would be different from the output focus (radius)

Comment: focus and waist is the same concept btw. The terminology for lasers is typically: beam waist: one sided $1/e$ field ($1/e^2$ intensity), so basically the radius of the focus. Beam diameter=beam waist*2. In my comprehension of your problem, as you need to compare output (measured) vs input (also measured) you do not need machine learning and much simpler algorithms following one scan of the variables should be more than enough. If needed you can add a physical model to make it more robust/versatile. But of course, that's my opinion after reading the information you gave.

Comment: Do you want your algorithm to work with a real electron microscope, or do you need to model the microscope with your algorithm?  In the first case, there is a pretty easy solution.  In the second case, it won't be nearly as easy.